# Backbone.Collection has no method toJSON

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone.js-collections

I'm writing a small app using Backbone. I start creating a SongsView which creates a SongsCollection. I fetch this collection to retrieve the data from an external API I wrote. The next step is to render the fetched data using the `toJSON` method, however calling `toJSON` returns `[undefined]`, despite the fact that the collection is an instance of Bakcbone.Collection.

Here is my code (in coffeescript):

App:

```
songs = new SongsView
songs.render()
```

SongsView:

```
SongsCollection = require 'scripts/collections/songs'

class SongsView extends Backbone.View

    el: '#songs'

    render: ->
        songs = new SongsCollection
        songs.fetch
            success: ( res ) =>
                console.log (res instanceof Backbone.Collection) # true
                console.log (res instanceof SongsCollection) # true
                console.log (res.toJSON()) # [undefined]
```

SongsCollection:

```
Song = require 'scripts/models/song'

class SongsCollection extends Backbone.Collection

    model: Song
    url: 'http://localhost:1337/songs'
```

Song:

```
class Song extends Backbone.Model

    constructor: ({@name, @path}) ->
        console.log 'new'
```

EDIT: If I look at the prototypes chain, I can find a toJSON() method though :
[image]

EDIT²: Same behavior for a single model :

```
console.log (res.models[0].toJSON()) # undefined
```

Which is actually interesting. It means that the `toJSON` method from the SongsCollection works but the `toJSON` from `Song` does not. I'll dig deeper there.

Comment: You try to call ``toJSON`` for collection, but you need to call this function for each model in collection

Comment: @jonijones Are you sure ? http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON

Comment: ``this.collection.each(function(){this.model.toJSON()}, this);``

Comment: In ``render()`` function your must have access for collection, in your case ``this.songs``. Try ``console.log(this.songs.toJSON);``. But for rendering, you need to render each model of collection.

Comment: Mmh. Actually, I think you are wrong. As specified in the link above, you can call `toJSON` on a collection. It returns the result of the method `toJSON`of each model. I found the solution of my problem, I'm using constructor instead of initialize which bypasses the Backbone.Model magic.

Comment: I do not argue what ``toJSON`` for collection return json representation for each model. But how you want to render collection not using models rendering?

Comment: Oh my bad. I know that though but you can avoid browsing each model. You need to pass the result of `collection.toJSON` to the template which iterates the data and manages the rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I was using `constructor` instead of `initialize` which leads to create a model without any `attributes`, thus, calling toJSON returned `undefined` as the `attributes` property was not defined.

```
class Song extends Backbone.Model

initialize: ({@name, @path}) ->
    console.log 'new'
```